# Google snippet not showing

Tags: html, rich-snippets

My google snippet not showing

Google testing tool:

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

My url:

http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imovel/apartamento-com-2-dorms-em-sao-paulo-jardim-brasil-zona-sul-por-1-ponto-4-mil/4801

The testing tools show ok for Offer and Product schema, but google snippet not showing!

Source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Apartamento com 2 dorms em São Paulo - Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul) por 1.4 mil | 
            JB Brasil Imóveis        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content=" JB Brasil Imóveis , Apartamento com 2 dorms em São Paulo - Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul) por 1.4 mil">
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='site-favicon.ico'/>
        <!-- Arquivo não encontrado: /resource/site/css/property/controller.css ?> --><!-- Arquivo não encontrado: /resource/site/css/property/view.css ?> --><!-- Arquivo não encontrado: /resource/site/css/module.css ?> --><link href="http://imob.io/resource/builds/css/9abae8dd7ef6a4110b18696dd66b591f8658892933.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom css filled in account config -->
<style type="text/css">
.animated.fadeIn.animate-delay-100 a:hover {color: black; }
.header-phone { font-size: 22px; color: #cc0000; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;}
.form-control:focus{border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0px #c3c3c3}
.row.result-box{ border-bottom: solid 2px #cc0000; box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #c3c3c3; padding-bottom: 10px}
.general-info-footer{margin-bottom: 10px
</style>                
        <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imovel/apartamento-com-2-dorms-em-sao-paulo-jardim-brasil-zona-sul-por-1-ponto-4-mil/4801">
 
<meta property="og:title" content="Apartamento com 2 dorms em São Paulo - Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul) por 1.4 mil">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="JB Brasil Imóveis">
 
<meta property="og:description" content="Apartamento com 2 dorms em São Paulo - Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul) por 1.4 mil">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://imob.io/data/1/photos/4801/55b7d28635c70-thumb.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400"> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300">
   
    </head>
    <body itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Product'>
        <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="dlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id='dialog-title'>Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Content</div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="/">
            <img src="/data/1/img/logo.png" alt="JB Brasil Imóveis">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
                            <img src="/resource/site/img/header/3.png" alt="Imóveis" height="150">
            </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="pull-right">
            
                        <div class="header-phone text-right">
                
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size: 24px;vertical-align: middle;"></i>
                                
                (11) 3562-5007            </div>
                        
                        <div class="header-phone text-right">
                
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size: 24px;vertical-align: middle;"></i>
                                
                (11) 9543-65186                
            </div>
                        
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#">JB Brasil Imóveis</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io" class="animated fadeIn animate-delay-100">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis" class="animated fadeIn animate-delay-200">Im&oacute;veis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/contato" class="animated fadeIn animate-delay-300">Contato</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/localizacao" class="animated fadeIn animate-delay-400">Localiza&ccedil;&atilde;o</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/sobre" class="animated fadeIn animate-delay-500">Quem somos</a></li>
                        
                                                
                        
                    </ul>
                    <form action="/imoveis" class="navbar-form navbar-right hidden-sm hidden-xs" role="search" method="get">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="reference" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Referência">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Procurar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class='breadcrumb'><li><a href='/imoveis'>Imóveis</a></li><li class='last-item'><h1 itemprop="name" >Apartamento com 2 dorms em São Paulo - Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul) por 1.4 mil</h1>
</li></ul>                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row visible-xs">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary side-bar-toggle" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="offcanvas"></span> Pesquisar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-offcanvas">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-xs side-bar">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading" >Pesquisa<a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/mapa-de-imoveis" class="pull-right">Ver no mapa</a></div>
<div class="panel-body collapse in" id="b12aa676128d9e3f74ea31d2e99b84a9" ><form method="GET" action="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="search-form"><div class="row" ><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="purpose" class="control-label">Finalidade</label><select class="form-control " id="purpose" name="purpose"><option value="" selected="selected">...</option><option value="1">Comprar</option><option value="2">Alugar</option></select></div></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="type" class="control-label">Tipo</label><select class="form-control " id="type" name="type"><option value="" selected="selected">...</option><option value="1">Casa</option><option value="2">Sobrado</option><option value="3">Apartamento</option><option value="6">Terreno</option><option value="7">Galp&atilde;o</option><option value="8">Sal&atilde;o Comercial</option><option value="9">Sala Comercial</option><option value="10">Ind&uacute;stria</option><option value="13">Duplex</option><option value="99">Outros</option></select></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row" ><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="bedroom" class="control-label">Dormit&oacute;rios</label><input min="1" max="99" class="form-control format-integer" id="bedroom" name="bedroom" type="number"></div></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="bathroom" class="control-label">Banheiros</label><input min="1" max="99" class="form-control format-integer" id="bathroom" name="bathroom" type="number"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row" ><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="suite" class="control-label">Su&iacute;tes</label><input min="1" max="99" class="form-control format-integer" id="suite" name="suite" type="number"></div></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="parking" class="control-label">Vagas</label><input min="1" max="99" class="form-control format-integer" id="parking" name="parking" type="number"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row" ><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="min_value" class="control-label">Valor (min)</label><input class="form-control format-money" id="min_value" name="min_value" type="text"></div></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" ><div class='form-group '><label for="max_value" class="control-label">Valor (max)</label><input class="form-control format-money" id="max_value" name="max_value" type="text"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row" ><div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ><div class='form-group '><label for="city" class="control-label">Cidade</label><select class="reload-select form-control" data-url="/get-neighborhoods-by-city" data-target="select[name=&#039;neighborhood&#039;]" id="city" name="city"><option value="" selected="selected">...</option><option value="S&atilde;o Paulo">S&atilde;o Paulo</option><option value="Jundia&iacute;">Jundia&iacute;</option><option value="S&atilde;o Bernardo do Campo">S&atilde;o Bernardo do Campo</option><option value="Monte Mor">Monte Mor</option><option value="Praia Grande">Praia Grande</option><option value="Juquitiba">Juquitiba</option></select></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row" ><div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ><div class='form-group '><label for="neighborhood" class="control-label">Bairro</label><select class="form-control " id="neighborhood" name="neighborhood"><option value="" selected="selected">...</option><option value="Vila do Encontro">Vila do Encontro</option><option value="Vila Santa Catarina">Vila Santa Catarina</option><option value="Vila Alexandria">Vila Alexandria</option><option value="Capela do Socorro">Capela do Socorro</option><option value="Vila Paulista">Vila Paulista</option><option value="Vila Constan&ccedil;a">Vila Constan&ccedil;a</option><option value="Conjunto Residencial Jardim Cana&atilde;">Conjunto Residencial Jardim Cana&atilde;</option><option value="Jardim Jabaquara">Jardim Jabaquara</option><option value="Interlagos">Interlagos</option><option value="Vila Campestre">Vila Campestre</option><option value="Jabaquara">Jabaquara</option><option value="Vila S&atilde;o Paulo">Vila S&atilde;o Paulo</option><option value="Vila Fachini">Vila Fachini</option><option value="Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul)">Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul)</option><option value="Jardim Prud&ecirc;ncia">Jardim Prud&ecirc;ncia</option><option value="Santo Amaro">Santo Amaro</option><option value="Vila Mascote">Vila Mascote</option><option value="Jardim Cid&aacute;lia">Jardim Cid&aacute;lia</option><option value="Vila Sofia">Vila Sofia</option><option value="Vila Arens II">Vila Arens II</option><option value="Vila Clementino">Vila Clementino</option><option value="Campininha">Campininha</option><option value="Parque Jabaquara">Parque Jabaquara</option><option value="Vila Nova Caled&ocirc;nia">Vila Nova Caled&ocirc;nia</option><option value="Parque Imperial">Parque Imperial</option><option value="Ipiranga">Ipiranga</option><option value="Vila Parque Jabaquara">Vila Parque Jabaquara</option><option value="Imirim">Imirim</option><option value="Planalto Paulista">Planalto Paulista</option><option value="Independ&ecirc;ncia">Independ&ecirc;ncia</option><option value="Jardim Miriam">Jardim Miriam</option><option value="Brooklin Paulista">Brooklin Paulista</option><option value="Vila Imp&eacute;rio">Vila Imp&eacute;rio</option><option value="Jardim Aeroporto">Jardim Aeroporto</option><option value="Jardim Figueira Grande">Jardim Figueira Grande</option><option value="Vila Babil&ocirc;nia">Vila Babil&ocirc;nia</option><option value="Jardim Oriental">Jardim Oriental</option><option value="Vila Marari">Vila Marari</option><option value="Cidade Ademar">Cidade Ademar</option><option value="Vila Joaniza">Vila Joaniza</option><option value="Vila Inglesa">Vila Inglesa</option><option value="S&atilde;o clemente">S&atilde;o clemente</option><option value="American&oacute;polis">American&oacute;polis</option><option value="Vila Mira">Vila Mira</option><option value="Maracan&atilde;">Maracan&atilde;</option><option value="Vila Monte Alegre">Vila Monte Alegre</option><option value="Cai&ccedil;ara">Cai&ccedil;ara</option><option value="Vila Andrade">Vila Andrade</option><option value="Vila Ol&iacute;mpia">Vila Ol&iacute;mpia</option><option value="Cidade Domitila">Cidade Domitila</option><option value="Fazenda da represa">Fazenda da represa</option><option value="Guilhermina">Guilhermina</option><option value="Vila do Castelo">Vila do Castelo</option></select></div></div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-left btn-clear" type="button" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" ></span>
 Limpar</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn pull-right" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span>
 Pesquisar</button>
</form></div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading" >Acesso rápido</div>
<div class="panel-body collapse in" id="30227cc9acdfd1b3212c9d5b1085939d" ><ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ><li><a href="/imoveis/?type=1" >Casa<span class="badge pull-right" >31</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=2" >Sobrado<span class="badge pull-right" >30</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=3" >Apartamento<span class="badge pull-right" >88</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=6" >Terreno<span class="badge pull-right" >1</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=7" >Galpão<span class="badge pull-right" >3</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=8" >Salão Comercial<span class="badge pull-right" >9</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=9" >Sala Comercial<span class="badge pull-right" >15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=10" >Indústria<span class="badge pull-right" >3</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=13" >Duplex<span class="badge pull-right" >1</span>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/imoveis/?type=99" >Outros<span class="badge pull-right" >4</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading" >Links úteis</div>
<div class="panel-body collapse in" id="025f4872f137648dce6fd8501aaf1d81" ><ul class="list-inline" ><li><a href="http://www.adminimoveis.com.br/" target="_blank" >ADMINIMÓVEIS LTDA.</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading" >Redes sociais</div>
<div class="panel-body collapse in" id="373e4808a0623b1732a1c1aa5e32045a" ><ul class="list-inline" ><li><a href="http://https://www.facebook.com/JB-Brasil-Im%C3%B3veis-LTDA-269140023137462/timeline/" target="_blank" >facebook</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
                </div>                
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    
<div class="row general-info">
    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
        <img id="main-photo" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail animated fadeIn" data-property-id="4801" itemprop='image' src="http://imob.io/data/1/photos/4801/55b7d28635c70-thumb.jpg" data-src="http://imob.io/data/1/photos/4801/55b7d28635c70-thumb.jpg" alt="DSC_0012">
    <img class="flag animated flipInX animate-delay-1000" alt='2 Dormitórios' src="/resource/site/img/flags/2.png">
    <img class='loading-galery hidden' alt='Carregando' src='/resource/common/img/loading.gif'>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
        <h4>Apartamento</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-right'>
        <span class="badge" style="margin: 5px;">Ref: 200</span>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row' itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12' >
        
        <div>Dorms: 2</div>
                <div>Vagas: 1</div>
        <div>Banheiros: 2</div>
        
        <div>Área útil (m2): 67,00</div>
        <div>Área priv. (m2): 67,00</div>
        <div>Area Total (m2): 67,00</div>
                        
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                
                            <div>Locação</div>
            <div><h4 itemprop="price"  class="text-primary"><strong>R$ 1.400,00</strong></h4></div>
            </div>    
    
</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center margin-bottom-10">
        <a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/contato/?reference=200" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Mais informa&ccedil;&otilde;es</a>
        <a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/financiamento" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Simular financimanto</a>                        
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row visible-xs">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center margin-bottom-10">
        <a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/contato/?reference=200" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs">Mais informa&ccedil;&otilde;es</a>
        <a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/financiamento" class="btn  btn-block btn-primary btn-xs">Simular financimanto</a>                        
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Descrição
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div itemprop="description">
            <p>
    Excelente oportunidade!!
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Apartamento</strong> com <strong>2 dorms(s)</strong> e <strong>1 vaga(s)</strong> em <strong>São Paulo SP</strong>
</p>
<p>
    Com um pequeno investimento de apenas <strong>R$ 0,00</strong> você pode realizar seu sonho!
</p>
<p>
    Este(a) <strong>Apartamento</strong> localizado(a) no bairro <strong>Jardim Brasil (Zona Sul)</strong> em <strong>São Paulo SP</strong>,
    tambem possue as seguintes caracteristicas:
</p>
<p>
    
</p>        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12">
        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Localização
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body no-padding">
        <div id="map" data-lat="-23.640579" data-lng="-46.666890"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">        
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span> Os preços e condições ora anunciados estão sujeitos a alteração sem prévio aviso.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        
               <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=452189481617186";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imovel/apartamento-com-2-dorms-em-sao-paulo-jardim-brasil-zona-sul-por-1-ponto-4-mil/4801" data-width='100%' data-numposts="5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imovel/apartamento-com-2-dorms-em-sao-paulo-jardim-brasil-zona-sul-por-1-ponto-4-mil/4801" data-layout="button_count"></div>
    </div>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 padding-5">
        <address>
            <strong>JB Brasil Imóveis</strong>
            <p id='address'>
                Avenida Doutor Lino de Moraes Leme, nº 1106
Vila Paulista - São Paulo - SP
CEP: 04360-000            </p>                
        </address>            
        <p>
            Creci: J. 21.330                
        </p>
            
        <abbr title="Telefones">Fone(s)</abbr>: (11) 3562-5007 (11) 9543-65186
        
            
            <div>Email: <a href="mailto:admjbbrasil@hotmail.com">admjbbrasil@hotmail.com</a></div>
                
                    
                
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 padding-5">
         
        <strong>Redes socias</strong>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            
                <li><a href="http://https://www.facebook.com/JB-Brasil-Im%C3%B3veis-LTDA-269140023137462/timeline/" target="_blank" >facebook</a>
</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
   
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 padding-5">
            
        <strong>Links úteis</strong>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            
                <li><a href="http://www.adminimoveis.com.br/" target="_blank" >ADMINIMÓVEIS LTDA.</a>
</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 padding-5">
        <strong>Imóveis</strong>
        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=1">Casa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=2">Sobrado</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=3">Apartamento</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=6">Terreno</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=7">Galp&atilde;o</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=8">Sal&atilde;o Comercial</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=9">Sala Comercial</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=10">Ind&uacute;stria</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=13">Duplex</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://jbbrasil.imob.io/imoveis?type=99">Outros</a></li>
                    </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <a href="http://imob.io">Desenvolvido por imob.io</a>
    </div>
</div>                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<!-- Arquivo não encontrado: /resource/site/js/property/controller.js ?> --><!-- Arquivo não encontrado: /resource/site/js/module.js ?> --><script src="http://imob.io/resource/builds/js/68e223b655cdebc0beeb25f30bb0e46818773178547.js"></script>
<script></script>    </body>
</html>
```

Any tip?

Comment: It can have [many different reasons](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/89650/17633). Unless the issue is with your code (which you haven’t included), this question seems to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se] (probably only if you can provide more details).

Comment: The code can be viewed in page source, but i put the content in my topic.

Answer (score 1):

Good Evening Joe,

For Product rich snippets eligibility you must markup Offer details.

I reviewed your markup and although Offer type is marked up it's not nested properly in Product type i.e. Product and Offer are marked up separately - see screenshot below.

[image: Testing Tool Results]

To nest Offer in Product you need to add the attribute, itemprop="offers" as indicated below.

`<div class='row' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">`

In addition, priceCurrency is required and the price value should not include any text, see below for markup suggestion.

`<h4 class="text-primary"><strong><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="INR"/>R$ <span itemprop="price" content="1.400.00">1.400,00</span></strong></h4>`

Also note, even if Google discovers technically correct markup on a page there's no guarantee they'll display rich snippets. Site must also meet quality requirements.

I hope the information is helpful.